# What <did you do><were you doing> yesterday between 8 and 9 p.m.?

Tags: tense

**Dialog 1**

Mary: What **did you do** yesterday between 8 and 9 p.m.?

Susan: I **studied** French.

**Dialog 2**

Judy: What **were you doing** yesterday between 8 and 9 p.m.?

Nancy: I **was studying** French.

[Question] Which dialog sounds natural?

I put the same question to two Japanese teachers of English, but their answers are different, hence this thread.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Dialogue 2 is more natural. If we are interested in a person's activities during a certain period of time, we usually think about a continuous action. However, it wouldn't be wrong to say "What did you do...?" if you thought the person might have performed some single action during that hour.

Even if she was asked "What did you do?", Susan would probably reply "I was studying French the whole time" or "I spent the time studying French."